# Multiple classes + ID's in CSS do the same?

Tags: css

You know in Java/PHP you can do something like this:

```
if (c.bigX == 1 || c.smallX == 2 || c.mediumX == 6) {
something here
}
```

How can I make it with CSS?

I have 5 classes, and I want them to do the same thing. instead of making a lot of lines.
Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

`.class1, .class2, .class3 {}` etc.

Comment: Can I have classes + ID's in same row?
.class1, #id1, .class2, #id2 { } ?

Answer (score 0):

Use commas in your selector:

```
.class1, .class2, .class3 {}
```

Bear in mind that each clause in such a list is a complete selector in its own right; that is

```
div .class1, .class2 {}
```

matches `class1` descendants of `div`s; and all `.class2` elements. If you wanted `class1` or `class2` descendants of `div`s, you need:

```
div .class1, div .class2 {}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.class1, .class2, .class3, .class4, .class5 {
  property:value;
}
```

This will help